# Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\scrapers\records.ibd

Tags: mysql, database, recovery

I have AMPPS installed on my Windows 10.

I was unable to start MySQL. I have searched through this error and tried different things to recover my data.

This was the error log:

```
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 132125643 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-02-03 10:19:54 6448 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace scrapers/openpasts_records which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\scrapers\openpasts_records.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\scrapers\openpasts_records.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

I have tried setting `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in my.cnf

Also I have tried removing `ibdata1` file as well.

After removing `ibdata1`, MySQL started perfectly.

and my table shows in PHPmyADMIN, but when I click on it it says `table does not exists even it exists`

In my `D:\Ampps\mysql\data\scrapers` directory, I can see `records.ibd` file and `records.frm` file as well. That means table physically exists but is corrupted.

Does someone know how do I recover that table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set value of

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

or 2 or 3 or 4
in my.ini file under [mysql]

try this hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: I added this to the my.ini file and it surely solved the issue.